# How do I make a command block kill a random player?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm working on something and to do so I need to have a command block kill a random block and not the same person everytime but I don't know if that is possible.

Comment: Would you want to immediately randomly kill someone, or are you wanting a random or automatic timer to go off and randomly kill someone?

Answer (score 2):

The player selector `@r` targets a random online player.

So you could use this command:

```
/kill @r
```